# MongoDB formatting timestamps to show 'how long ago ' text

Tags: javascript, mongodb

MongoDB stores this in the database:

```
createdAt:2021-01-19T15:03:31.645+00:00
```

How would I be able to extract this into a usable format? Also, is there an easy way for me to do something like: 'created 1 day ago'

Comment: Welcome! That date property appears to be something from mongoose, not MongoDB native. I don't think you'll be able to change that. You would need to some type of parsing and conversion to create a more friendly version for viewing (doesn't make sense storing something like "one day ago" in the database, since it becomes obsolete fairly quickly). What have you tried, regarding date parsing and formatting? I'd suggest editing your question to show what you've tried, where you're stuck, output issues, errors, etc.

Comment: Use [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) or libraries like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/). moments.js also support functions like `moment().subtract(1, 'day').toDate()`

Comment: Why do yon consider the ISO-8601 format as "unusable"?